# Selenium Webdriver Ruby Send_keys control chars

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm trying to type a ® in an input field through capybara / selenium.

```
firefox browser
capybara (2.1.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.32.1)
```

I believe that I should be able to send_keys [:alt, 'r']?

Is the latest version of selenium-webdriver + ruby broken? Because sending anything complex to sendkeys gives me this:

```
>> field.native.send_keys 'b','c',[:control, 'a'], 'a'                                                                                                     

>> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: JSON.parse: unterminated string literal
```

A little context: 
I used to do this through JS, but for some reason, whenever I run much JS through the execute_script it gives a script_unresponsive alert box about 50% of the time.  I've been adjusting the timeouts on the browser and it's a hard lock (forever).  We've got a pretty complex application and I've spend a good amount of time investigating.  So I'm trying to do this WITHOUT javascript - since for some reason my cukes start to pass/fail 50% of the time.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: 1. I would send the ® because how to type the ® highly depends on keyboard defaults and this depends on the user of the browser. 2. I would write `'control'` and not `:control` because json does not know symbols, it uses strings. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is press ALT+R using send keys and Ruby this is what you need to do:

```
require 'win32ole'
skey = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')

skey.sendKeys('%{r}')
```

Tested the above with ALT+V and selenium and it is working as intended.

Let me know if you still need further help.

Best of luck!

PS. (% stands for ALT), (^ is CTRL)